# Retrieving similar values from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using MS SQL Server and have a database table that contains customer contact information, the car that was bought, and who sold the car.  I need to get customers names but only if they bought a car that at least 30 other people also bought in the same year.  I can get the customer contact info and car info but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to return the results only for cars that at least 30 people bought.

the specific columns in the Car_sales table are `customer_first, customer_last, customer_email, salesperson_first, salesperson_last, car_model_id`

the car_model_id column holds values like '5826', '7256', etc... so I would need to get customer info only in the case where '5826' appears at least 30 times in the column.

this is what I started working with but it dies not return the desired results.  I'm not too sure how to return customer info that purchased the same car as 30 other people.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_first, customer_last, customer_email
FROM Car_sales 
GROUP BY customer_first, customer_last, customer_email
HAVING COUNT(car_model_id) >= 30
```

Comment: add the model id as the `where` condition

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select *
from car_sales cs1
where exists (
  select 1
  from car_sales cs2
  where cs1.car_model_id = cs2.car_model_id
  group by cs2.car_model_id
  having count(*) >= 30
  )
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXKU7jkB2CjJCwVZbYboF/0)

---

Or since you are using `sql server`, you can use a `window function`:

```
select *
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by car_model_id) cnt
  from car_sales) t
where cnt >= 30
```

- [More Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iXKU7jkB2CjJCwVZbYboF/1)

Comment: Thank you.  Your first query is what I was looking for.  I ran into an issue though when there are duplicate records, for example if someone bought 2 cars they show up twice in the 30 car output.  I've been trying to figure out how to filter the results so that only 1 customer contact is returned and `distinct` doesn't seem to be doing the trick for some reason.

Comment: To avoid the duplicate customers, you can just use the select clause from your original question in either of these queries. `SELECT DISTINCT customer_first, customer_last, customer_email`. You can't use `DISTINCT *` to avoid duplicating the customer information, since the salesperson and model likely aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using sub-queries.

```js
SELECT car_sales.* ,
       car_sales_thirty.total_sales
FROM car_sales
JOIN
  (SELECT car_model_id AS cmi,
          COUNT(car_model_id) AS total_sales
   FROM car_sales
   GROUP BY car_model_id) AS car_sales_thirty ON car_sales_thirty.cmi = car_sales.car_model_id
WHERE total_sales >= 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked sgeddes `window function` answer the best and voted for it, but I'd like to post two alternate answers. I don't think these are as good as the `window function` answer, but I personally feel they are more readable than the `exists` answer.

Even though I imagine the DB will be smart enough to treat this the same as the `exists` version, I think it's conceptually simpler to imagine this `in` version running one query in the where-clause as opposed to many:

```
select distinct customer_first, customer_last, customer_email
from car_sales cs1
where cs1.car_model_id IN (
  select cs2.car_model_id
  from car_sales cs2
  group by cs2.car_model_id
  having count(*) >= 30
  )
```

I also think doing a simple count is pretty clear:

```
select distinct customer_first, customer_last, customer_email
from car_sales cs1
where (select count(*) from car_sales cs2 WHERE cs2.car_model_id = cs1.car_model_id) >= 30
```